# Fields and Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I think this is straight forward, but I want to make sure:

Claim: Let $R$ be a commutative ring. $R$ is a field if and only if $(0)$ is a maximal ideal.

Proof: Every ideal of $R$ must contain $0$, but because $(0)$ is a maximal ideal, the only ideals that contain $(0)= 0$ are $(0)$ and $R$. Thus the only two ideals of $R$ are $(0)$ and $R$. Thus (by a proposition proven in the text: $R$ is a field iff $(0)$ and $R$ are the only ideals) $R$ is a field.

Answer (score 1):

The short version, using the proposition mentioned, is showing:

> $(0)$ is maximal if and only if $(0)$ and $R$ are the only ideals of $R$.

Then the proposition shows that $(0)$ is maximal if and only if $R$ is a field.

Your proof, as stated, seems to only show that if $(0)$ is maximal, then $R$ is a field.

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean.